# $\int_0^T t^{2a}K_a(t)^2\;dt=\text{ ?}$ where $K_a$ is modified Bessel function of second kind?

Tags: integration, reference-request, bessel-functions

Let $K_a$ be the modified Bessel function of second kind, with $a>0$ a real number.

Is there a nice expression for 
$$\int_0^T t^{2a} K_a(t)^2\;dt,$$
where $T < \infty$?

The expression for $K_a$ is a horrible looking infinite sum, so I was hoping for a reference. I tried various books containing tables of such integrals but wasn't able to find the one I wanted.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @tired It looks too difficult to do by hand because $K_a$ has a nasty expression. So I was hoping to find a reference for this info.

Comment: $$\frac{\pi  \Gamma \left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(2 a+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4 \Gamma (a+1)}$$ is the result given by mathematica if $T=\infty$, looks not so bad

Comment: @tired: that result can be recovered from Parseval's theorem and the orthogonality of Bessel's polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_polynomials)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks! i figured it a few minutes ago.. :)

Answer (score 1):

$t^a K_a(t)$ is a multiple of the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{(1+s^2)^{a+1/2}}$, hence by Parseval's identity the integral for $T=+\infty$ just depends on the integral:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{(1+s^2)^{2a+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\left(2a+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma(2a+1)} $$ 
that can be computed by setting $s=\tan(\theta)$ then recalling the properties of Euler's [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). For large $a$s we have:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{2a}K_a(t)^2\,dt \approx \left(\frac{2a}{e}\right)^{2a}\sqrt{\frac{\pi^3}{8a}}.$$

Comment: Thanks but what about if $T$ is infinite?

Comment: @TagCharacters: it is the only case I dealt with, $T$ being plus infinity.

Comment: Ok. Do you know if how to calculate $\int_0^T tK_a(t)^2$? It's simpler than the other one

Comment: @TagCharacters: it has a non-integrable singularity in the origin.